# Differences dpi for Android and Samsung Ace mobile

Tags: android, dpi

Specifications:
Samsung Galaxy Ace: LCD TFT / 3.5 inch / 480 x 320 pixels / 164 dpi.

but:

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

float V_dpi = metrics.densityDpi;

V_dpi = 160 but technical characteristics is 164.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in [the documentation for `densityDpi`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#densityDpi):

> The screen density expressed as dots-per-inch. May be either
>   `DENSITY_LOW`, `DENSITY_MEDIUM`, or `DENSITY_HIGH`.

In other words: it doesn't contain the actual density value, but rather the bucket in which it fits. Hence, the value will always be one of the following:

```
DENSITY_LOW = 120;
DENSITY_MEDIUM = 160;
DENSITY_HIGH = 240;
DENSITY_TV = 213;
DENSITY_XHIGH = 320;
DENSITY_XXHIGH = 480;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `metrics.ydpi` and `metrics.xdpi` I think those values are more accurate.